# Google Plus emailing pictures

Tags: google-plus

I have all of my photos in Google Plus. I can share the photos but how can I just pick a picture and email to someone instead of the sharing option.

Answer (score 1):

You can either...

Share with only one person (instead of a Circle). The recipient will receive an email notification. The person doesn't need to be a Google+ user, either. You can use their email address.

...or...

Download the photo and attach it to an email message manually.

Comment: I type in there email address but they never get it

Comment: Spam folder, maybe? That's the way to do it. I don't have any other suggestions for you.